# Share credit of an answer

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes any user comes up as a hero to suggest something which can *definitely improve my answer* and I should add his name in the answer *as suggested by `@User`* but that doesn't inform the user at least.

My question is, is there any better way to *tag* that *Hero user* to my answer?

Should I also provide link to the user's profile?

*NOTE:Ideally my answer should be accurate.!! :)*

Comment: There's no way to notify the user of the addition to the answer, other replying to the user's comment with an @at. I usually link to the user's comment & profile, when I quote the suggestion...

Comment: Great suggestion @Cerbrus! I've added it to [my answer.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274511/1835379)

Comment: @Cerbrus Your [comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274510/share-credit-of-answer#comment106035_274510) which includes link to the answer is more better in this situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like [@Cerbrus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/cerbrus) [posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274510/share-credit-of-answer#comment106031_274510):

> There's no way to notify the user of the addition to the answer, other replying to the user's comment with an @at.
>   I usually link to the user's comment & profile, when I quote the suggestion...

Comment: Please don't tell me you got a notification from that comment :-)

Comment: @Bergi: I won't, cause then I'd be lying :P